# What is the root logger in log4net

Tags: log4net

I don't quite understand what the main functionality for root logger as shown in following section is. What is the difference from other loggers?

```
<root>
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the log4net [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/introduction.html#hierarchy) explains this quite nicely:

Loggers are organized in hierarchies. E.g.: The logger `Foo.Bar` is child of the logger `Foo`. This way the loggers create a tree and the root logger is simply the root of that tree (in the example Foo is a child of the root logger).

This hiearchy allows for some interesting configuration applications (e.g. disable/enable logging for an entire sub system of your application).

Answer (score 3):

The Root Logger can hold a list of appenders and settings (typically just the log level) used when logging.

Check [this link](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) for more details about the Root Logger with Log4net.